# JQuery Load not able to pass value to the controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass a complex object to the controller through ajax Load(), however im getting a null object on the controller.

Ive seen some questions on this however they are on codeIgniter, I am using MVC.NET

Here's my code :

```
$('#btnLoadMore').on('click', function () {
        dataObject.PageIndex = dataObject.PageIndex + 1;
        $("#viewPlaceHolder").load("/home/GetPagedData",
       { data: JSON.stringify(dataObject), contentType: 'application/json', type: 'post' });
    });
```

and this code below which is on the search click button is working fine.

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {
        var startDate = $('#StartDate').val();
        var endDate = $('#EndDate').val();
        dataObject= {
            'UserId': 1,
            'PageIndex': pageIndex,
            'PageSize': pageSize,
            'StartDate': startDate,
            'EndDate': endDate
        };      
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetPagedData", "Home")',
            contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    async: true,

    data: JSON.stringify(dataObject)
    ,
    success: function (result) {
        $('#pricing-table').html(result);
        window.location = "#pricing";

    }
    });
    });
```

Comment: Quick question, what is the `type` for, you know `jQuery.load` only does get requests, and inserts the returned HTML directly into the DOM ?

Comment: yup, it is supposed to inject returned HTML into the page, I have the placeholder div as well, but am not able to pass values despite changing the type to get

Comment: Well, the data is being sent, but you seem to be using the same settings as `$.ajax` which `load` doesn't have. The object you're sending is treated as the data you'd normally put in the `data` property in `$.ajax`, setting a type or contentType inside the object does nothing, as the contentType is HTML and the type is GET, always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [jQuery Load article](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise,
>   GET is assumed.

You can provide in `load` method only url, data, complete callback parameters.

So your code should looks like this:

```
$('#btnLoadMore').on('click', function () {
    dataObject.PageIndex = dataObject.PageIndex + 1;
    $("#viewPlaceHolder").load("@Url.Action("GetPagedData","Home")",
    dataObject);
});
```